# Traceur.js vs Traceur-runtime.js

Tags: javascript, traceur, angular

When I cloned and build `traceur` I got 2 files installed: `traceur.js` and `traceur-runtime.js`.

The `traceur` docs([specifically](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/Building-custom-Traceur-runtimes)) here won't really explain the difference between the `traceur.js` and `traceur-runtime.js`.

I know that `traceur.js` contains the content of `traceur-runtime.js` and the `traceur-runtime.js` is a small part of `traceur.js`.

I understand `traceur.js` can be used by NodeJS, `traceur.js` + `bootstrap.js(just for initiation)` used for the browser use, `traceur-runtime.js` is used by Angular2.

**My questions:**

- What are the differences?
- Why Angular2 only require `traceur-runtime.js`?
- What functionalities from `traceur.js` does `traceur-runtime.js(28k lines less)` removes?
- Do both shim the missing functions?
- What each is used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on this, but *traceur-runtime* is just the polyfills that your browser needs to use es6 features while *traceur* is the full node tool for compiling es6 to es5.

Angular2 uses TypeScript to compile to es5, but you still need to polyfill in modular loading ie. `System.import('')` so you can load only what your app needs. Otherwise angular needs to be bound to the window along with **all** of the Angular2 code.

Comment: `traceur` is used to compile `es6` to `es5`, but the `es5` codes need `traceur-runtime` to excute. Now angular2 have abandon `traceur` now, please use `Typescript` !